# How do i run a program before user login on Windows?

Tags: windows, startup, boot

I have searched all over the internet for this but can't seem to find the answer I am looking for. Basically I want to execute a program before the shell starts, before the user even logs in. I am creating a boot time virus scanner and I would like the user to be able to see what is going on and interact with it (eg, press 'escape' to exit, and so on). So basically I want to do what antivirus companies are doing with boot-time scans, but I have no idea of where to even begin. Thanks.

Comment: You can use the `BootExecute` registry key to run a native application (`/SUBSYSTEM:NATIVE`) when the system boots.  There's very little documentation on writing native applications, though.

Comment: @Harry Johnston- This may be a stupid question, but what do you mean by 'native application'. Does a python script compiled to machine code count as a 'native application.'

Comment: [Wikipedia has an article on the Native API.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_API)  No, a compiled Python script would be a Win32 application, not a Native API application.  (Well, it would be possible in principle to write a Python compiler that produced Native API applications, but it is unlikely that anyone has ever done so.)

Comment: Note that the phrase "native application" can have two different meanings in Windows: it may mean a Win32 application as opposed to a .NET CLR application, or it may mean a Native API application as opposed to a Win32 application.  I meant the latter.  The former meaning is more recent but also much more common.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Your answer is exactly what I was looking for. If you'd answer the question it would definately be the accepted answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the BootExecute registry key to run a [Native API application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_API) (/SUBSYSTEM:NATIVE) when the system boots.

However, use of the Native API from user mode is not supported or officially documented, so Here Be Dragons.  Be aware that your application might break unexpectedly in newer versions of Windows or even when updates are installed.

The supported approach for anti-virus software is to use kernel-mode device drivers.  The [Kernel Data and Filtering Support for Vista SP1](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=ObRegisterCallbacks&ac=4) document from Microsoft may be of interest here.

To avoid confusion, readers should note that the phrase "native application" can have at least two different meanings in Windows: it may mean a Win32 application as opposed to a .NET CLR application, or it may mean a Native API application as opposed to a Win32 application.  (I've also seen it used to mean a Win32 application as opposed to, for example, a Python script.)

Answer (score 0):

tis a long shot, but you may want to take a look at [gina.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163803.aspx).  This is the DLL that handles the secure attention sequence (ctrl-alt-del) key stroke, and logging the user on among other things.  I know the article is old, but I believe it is still relevant.

You may be able to accomplish what you want by reimplementing parts of this dll.

Comment: GINA is not supported in Vista and above.

Comment: Did not know that.  What, if anything, is the replacement to GINA?

Comment: Credential provider. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff404303(v=ws.10).aspx